# Sequel generate migration

Tags: ruby, sequel

I see that the Sequel gem supports migrations [here](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html), but I don't see any type of generator documented.  Does one exist; or should I be manually creating all of my migrations (or alternately creating my own task to generate migrations)?

Comment: At my workplace, we have Sinatra/Sequel, and manually create migrations. That might simply be because we don't know any better (hence I cannot make this an answer).

Comment: @MarcoPrins, I use Rails for some projects; typically large monolithic web sites. For this particular case I'm using Sinatra to build a Restful web service.

Comment: Looks like a generator does not exist for Sequel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/migration.rdoc#creating-a-migration):

> **Sequel doesn't come with generators** that create migrations for you. However, creating a migration is as simple as creating a file with the appropriate filename in your migrations directory that contains a `Sequel.migration` call.

The contents of the migration file doesn't have to specify a timestamp or index and it's an extremely simple format.

I generally just copy a previous migration (maybe one similar to the migration I'm creating) and alter the filename. See existing migrations with:

```
$ ls -1 db/migrate/
20170320075430_check_postgres_extensions.rb
...
```

For running migrations, I use the rake task that's available [here](https://gist.github.com/kalmbach/4471560).

Answer (score 4):

Sequel has no migration generator. But you can easily write your own, for example using a rake task. Here is one:

```
# Rakefile
require 'fileutils'

namespace :db do
  MIGRATIONS_DIR = 'db/migrations'

  desc "generates a migration file with a timestamp and name"
  task :generate_migration, :name do |_, args|
    args.with_defaults(name: 'migration')

    migration_template = <<~MIGRATION
      Sequel.migration do
        up do
        end

        down do
        end
      end
    MIGRATION

    file_name = "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}_#{args.name}.rb"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(MIGRATIONS_DIR)

    File.open(File.join(MIGRATIONS_DIR, file_name), 'w') do |file|
      file.write(migration_template)
    end
  end
end
```

Then run the rake task like this `rake db:generate_migration[my_migration_name]`. This command will create a Sequel migration file `20220720233750_my_migration_name.rb` in the directory `db/migrations`.